# QML state changes on "when" clause sets default state

Tags: qt, qml

When using the `when` clause of a QML state, it sometimes goes through the default state (`""`) before going to the final state:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

Button {
    id: root

    width: 30
    height: 30

    states: [
        State {
            name: "PRESSED"
            when: pressed
        },
        State {
            name: "NOTPRESSED"
            when: !pressed
        }
    ]

    onStateChanged: {
        console.log("State: " + state);
    }
}
```

`pressed` here is a boolean, so whatever its value, `onStateChanged()` should be triggered with one of the states I defined. But here, the output is:

```
$ qmlscene ./Button.qml
qml: State: NOTPRESSED
qml: State: 
qml: State: PRESSED
qml: State: NOTPRESSED
qml: State: 
qml: State: PRESSED
qml: State: NOTPRESSED
qml: State: 
qml: State: PRESSED
qml: State: NOTPRESSED
```

Why does Qt changes the state from `NOTPRESSED` to `""` before setting the target state `PRESSED`?

I've tested this component with Qt 5.14.1 and 5.15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State **""** means [released](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#released-signal). If you put in your code this:

```
State {
    name: "released"
    when: root.released
}
```

**Full code:**

```
Button {
    id: root
    autoRepeat: true

    anchors.fill: parent

    states: [
        State {
            name: "PRESSED"
            when: root.pressed
        },
        State {
            name: "NOTPRESSED"
            when: !root.pressed
        },
        State {
            name: "released"
            when: root.released
        }
    ]

    onStateChanged: {
        console.log("State: " + state);
    } 
}
```

You will see, that **""** will be changed to **released**.

*My output, If someone need:*

```
qml: State: NOTPRESSED
qml: State: released
qml: State: PRESSED
```

Comment: This answer is a Workaround only even if it has been selected as best answer by the. See @paul s answer for the correct and elaborative answer.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: it's a QT Bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86695

--

The problem with the `when` clause enabling the default unnamed state `""` in some situations, even if it does not appear in the list of states is not specific to `Button`. If you have more than one state and transitions between states, you usually can't use the `when` clause anymore until this bug is fixed.

If you have only two states you may avoid the unnamed `""` default state as follows:

1. put the default state at the end of the state array and
2. specify `when: 1 == 1` (if you do not need to support QT 5.12 you may also write `when: true` here).

To see how this workaround fixes the OPs problem consider the following example (deliberately not using `Button` to also show that the problem is much more general and is not related to the `released` state of Button):

```
Item {
    id: item
    anchors.fill: parent

    property bool toggle

    Button {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: item.toggle = ! item.toggle
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "true"
            when: item.toggle
        },
        State {
            name: "false"
            when: ! item.toggle
        }
    ]

    onStateChanged: {
        console.log("state:", state, "toggle:", toggle)
    }
}
```

In QT 5.12.9 clicking twice produces the following output (first line on startup)

```
qml: state: false toggle: false
qml: state: true toggle: true
qml: state: false toggle: false
```

In QT 5.15.2 clicking twice produces the following output (first line on startup)

```
qml: state: false toggle: false
qml: state:  toggle: true
qml: state: true toggle: true
qml: state: false toggle: false
```

So switching form `toggle: false` to `toggle: true` goes through the `""` default state in QT 5.15.2 rather than directly to the `"true"` state. If you change the sequence of state definitions, the other state change goes through `""`. It looks like there is a moment when the `when` clause of the `"false"` state is `false`, but the when clause of the `"true"` state is not `true` yet.

In QT 5.15.2 specifying `when: true` on the `"false`" state works, i.e. the states toggle as in QT 5.12.9 and the default unnamed `""` state is never applied. But this workaround produces an error (Invalid property assignment: unsupported type "QQmlBinding*") in QT 5.12.9 (which I also need to support). This error is avoided by `when: 1 == 1`. So here is my final workaround:

```
Item {
    id: item
    anchors.fill: parent

    property bool toggle

    Button {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: item.toggle = ! item.toggle
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "true"
            when: item.toggle
        },
        State {
            name: "false"
            when: 1 == 1
        }
    ]

    onStateChanged: {
        console.log("state:", state, "toggle:", toggle)
    }
}
```